# Same step name in two diffrent feature file

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cucumber, cypress, gherkin

trying to automate tests using gherkin, cucumber and cypress. I write the test scenario in *.feature files and the code in *.js files.

He wants to test module by module. The first to test went the login module, and the next is the registration module.

**login.feature**

```
Feature: Login page

    Feature Login page will work depending on the user credentials.

    Background:
        Given A user opens a website to log in
    Scenario: Success Login as Agent
        When A user enters the username "agent"
        And A user enters the password "pass!"
        And A user clicks on the login button
        Then The user was logged in as an Agent
    Scenario: Success Login as Customer
        When A user enters the username "customer"
        And A user enters the password "pss123!"
        And A user clicks on the login button
        Then The user was logged in as an Customer
    Scenario: Success Login as Admin
        When A user enters the username "admin"
        And A user enters the password "admin1"
        And A user clicks on the login button
        Then The user was logged in as an Admin
    Scenario: Log in to the wrong user
        When A user enters the username "1qazxsw23edc"
        And A user enters the password "1qazxsw23edc"
        And A user clicks on the login button
        Then Error when logging in to the wrong user
```

**registration.feature**

```
Feature: New user registration.

    Feature is designed to test the operation of registration.

    Background:
        Given A user opens a website to register
    Scenario: Correct registration of a new user
    When User clicks on button to register
        And A user enters the username "cypress_agent"
        And A user enters the email "cypress_test@gmail.com"
        And A user enters the first name "Cypress"
        And A user enters the last name "Test"
        And A user enters the password "zaq1@WSX"
        And A user enters the password confirmation "zaq1@WSX"
        And A user clicks on the submit button
        Then TBA
```

The problem arises when trying to fire off whichever feature file that the steps repeat, which is true because the steps "A user opens a website to log in" or "A user enters the username {string}".

```
Error
Multiple matching step definitions for: A user enters the username "cypress_agent"
A user enters the username {string}
A user enters the username {string}
```

The simplest solution would be to change the name. However, I am told that the farther into testing eventually the same name will repeat. Is there any other solution to this problem? E.g. to make the login.js file use ONLY login.feature and the same for registration. Unless you recommend some other solution. Thank you in advance and best regards.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to arrange your test files more rationally. You don't need to change the name of the file or change anything. But you keep in mind the notion of reusability and scaleability. Since you already have one generic step in step definition and it's enough for you i.e.

```
 A user enters the username {string}
```

and in feature file you can call with any string relevant to your feature, which you already did i.e.

```
A user enters the username "cypress_agent"
```

and in some other feature

```
 A user enters the username "agent"
```

It calls the same step as you make the step dynamic in nature. So IMHO you have to get ride of duplicate steps and cucumber will take care of it.